# Change solution directories of Azure web app

Tags: azure

I recently changed around some solution folder names and project file names to meet a company standard. This all works locally, but when I went to deploy it to our Azure instance, the continuous integration on Azure (using bitbucket) is still trying to reference the .csproj is the old directory.

`[D:\home\site\repository\OldDirectory\MarketingPortal.csproj]`

Note the `OldDirectory` in the msbuild command that Azure is showing in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

Open the solution file in a text editor and modify the reference to the csproj.